# Pandas: Subtract rows in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like the below.

```
    Day    | Price
12-05-2015 |  73
12-06-2015 |  68
11-07-2015 |  77
10-08-2015 |  54
```

I would like to subtract the price for one `Day` from the corresponding price 30 days later. To add to the days, I've used `data.loc[data['Day'] + timedelta(days=30)]` however this obviously overflowed near the final dates in my dataframe. Is there a way to subtract the prices without iterating over all the rows in the dataframe?

If it helps, my desired output is something like the following.

```
 Start_Day    | Price
12-05-2015    |  -5
11-07-2015    |  -23
```

Comment: There are 31 days between the 12th of May and the 12th of June. Typo?

Comment: @IanS: Yes, my mistake. But the general idea is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `df.diff()` function.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html